# Битрикс интеграция с Битрикс24

Tags: битрикс, битрикс24, интеграция, crm

Включил стандартную интеграцию в Битрикс управление сайтом  с битрикс24 crm.

Не был удивлен что все сделано через жопу. Сделки которые приходят в CRM имеют странный формат. Не передаются контактные данные физ. лица, заполняется название компании формата #test#Имя и все. Никаких телефонов, e-mail и так далее. Ранее имел опыт работы с вебхуками битрикс24 и спокойно интегрировал все на других проектах(не на битрикс).

Подскажите пожалуйста как можно проще всего решить эту проблему. Первое что пришло на ум это использовать в php_interface в **init.php** перехват события **OnBeforeCrmDealAdd** (перед добавлением сделки и пытаться отформатировать данные в нужном формате или типо того). Или выключить стандартную интеграцию и перехватывать событие оформление заказа что то типо **OnSaleComponentOrderCreated** или **OnSaleComponentOrderResultPrepared**.

Помогите люди добрые! Спасибо.

Comment: Битрикс24 отлично работает со входящими и исходящими веб-хуками https://helpdesk.bitrix24.ru/open/5408147/

Comment: ты не ответил на вопрос, то что битрикс24 работает с вебхуками это как сказать, что солнце светит, ничего не ответил. Мне вырубать в битрикс CMS стандартную интеграцию и отсылать при формировании заказа исходящий вебхук или можно сделать все элегантнее?

Comment: я вам ответ и не давал. Я лишь предложил использоватьь веб-хуки. Хотя мне помнится, что интеграция БУС с Б24 передает информацию о заказчике в сделку. Она ее пишет в одно из полей сделки. Контакт или Компанию, да она создавать не умеет. Да и почему-то сделка создается, а не Счет. `OnBeforeCrmDealAdd` вы где использовать собираетесь? На стороне Б24 или сайта? На стороне сайта вы не сможете, т.к. у БУС нет сделок. Ну и основной вопрос какой у вас битрикс24 облако или коробка.

Comment: БУС  при стандартной интеграции с битрикс24 создает сделки при оформлении заказа и делает это криво. Стоит задача исправить косяки. Погуглил на этот счет и как оказалось это проблемы разрабов, то что они сделали косячную интеграцию, которую надо переписывать. Я так понял мне теперь при оформлении заказа надо перехватит событие OnSaleComponentOrderCreated и сделать исходящий вебхук с грамотно сформированным массивом, а не как сейчас. Битрикс24 облачный.